# When company doesn’t achieve targets I am blamed by my boss. Our monthly targets are set up very high

Tags: salary, manager, india, workload, middle-east

I joined my present company 6 years ago. I had to join without any options as my residency was getting over (my home country is India), and only this company provided it.

We started with monthly target of 6000 Kuwaiti Dinars. After 6 years we do 40000 Kuwaiti Dinars every month. This is very difficult to maintain every month due to market competition. We are consistently growing by 75% year-on-year.

My boss had a very big financial loss 3 years ago. He just pays me 30% of my salary and incentive every month. The leftover amount is huge and he tells me he will pay. I have no legal document to prove for the left over amount.

If during any month we don’t reach our target, he doubts my work ethics and thinks that I purposely don’t work. From last 6 years I have been working minimum 11 hours daily. In total I have not taken more than 100 days leave in 6 years.

The issue is that half of my salary is 2 times more than the market value salary. And if I leave him, he will not pay me the remaining balance.

What options do I have, and what should I do?

Comment: What is "residency" and what happens to you if you don't have it?

Comment: Do you have any documentation at all? Employment contract, hiring letter, pay stubs?

Comment: What do you mean, "my half salary..."? Are you being paid 30% of your agreed rate or 50%?

Comment: I stay in Kuwait. The visa which allows you to work in th country is called Residency.

Comment: I am the senior most employee. When we were doing 6000 KWD. My boss didnt imagine that we will some day achieve 40,000 KWD. He had kept me on targets, My basic salary is 500 KD and on achivement of targets there is percentage. if we achieve 40000 , He would pay 3

Comment: Maybe cut your losses.  Just leave, return to your own county, and call it a loss.

Comment: That sounds like a scam. You have no proof but are promises a huge fortune in some undefined future. At Financial.SE you see this pattern a lot. The bitter truth is that you will never see that money.

Comment: Assume that you are never going to get that unpaid salary.  All the time you stay, you are not getting it.  If you leave, you have no proof you are owed it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kuwait law, but paying someone 30% of their agreed salary is illegal in every other territory I'm familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.
Please let me know what should I do.
I have a family and my fixed expenses are increasing day by day.

Comment: @Abdemus: find another job.  That's what you should do.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice.
TO go to any other country i have to get work visa, Regarding my home country India. Our situations are very worst. The unemployment rate is the highest in 70 years.
I want to change my job but whenever I see my old parents who are depended on me I go for job. It has turn out to be vicious circle, which is happening every 3 months. If I intend to leave the job I have to first arrange a work visa for me, That is by finding another job or pay a hefty amount by bribing government officials. I am utterly confused. Please Please Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: What does "half of my salary is 2 times more than the market value salary" mean?

Comment: It has been great advice, But the fear of searching a job and being unemployed is scary, Moreover the fear of regret in future that" I wish i should not have change the job" this issues are creating too many obstacles. Thanks

Comment: @berry120 Legal protections for foreigners in Kuwait are not enforced.  It may be illegal but if the courts are unwilling to side with outsiders to fix the situation legality really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Abdemus Have you recently asked about going back to getting your full salary since the company is doing so well?

Comment: I have asked many times, However my boss who is also the owner keeps on telling that he has incurred a huge loss and is still recovering from it, Once that loss is covered than he will pay.

Comment: added line that OP is from India. As foreigner OP seems to be abused by the employer

Comment: @stannius. Half of my salary means that the amount what am i earning inn my company is the two times what I will get when I will leave the company

Comment: So your official salary is 4 times the market rate? But the actual pay you are receiving is only 30% of your official salary? So basically you are getting paid market rate but with unfulfilled promises to pay more?

Comment: Dear Mr.stannius what i get in hand is 1000 KD however in market in pay is 500 kd

Comment: Is it legal not to pay!?

Comment: i have no documents to prove my balance of payment

Answer (score 12):

1) Whatever you do, start searching for another job.  That is most important.

2) You will not see those missing 70% of your monthly salary, ever.  It is gone, your boss has stolen it from you, and your boss will continue to steal it from you each month for the foreseeable future.  When you say "if I leave him, he will not pay me the remaining balance", the truth is that if you stay, he will also not pay you the remaining balance.  It's gone.

3) Decide if 30% of your salary (the 30% you are receiving) is enough money to continue to work 11-hour days and handle the stress of this company.  If it is, then stay (and continue searching for another job).  If it's not, then leave (and search for another job while unemployed).

Comment: Have you taken into account that OP is working in a golf emirate (those are notorious for giving few rights to foreign workers) and is probably from a developing country? Finding another job, preferably a better job, might be extremely difficult for them.

Comment: @Roland While that sucks for OP, it literally makes no difference as to what the correct advice is.  Also, OP is not limited to finding a job in Kuwait.

Comment: @JimClay OP is limited to countries which will grant them a work visa. I don't know their specific circumstances but that is likely a major issue. And possibly they can't just leave because their family would literally starve.

Comment: @Roland He always has the option of his home country, and he may be able to go to other countries.  Regarding starving- that is why you look for another job while you are still working.

Comment: Also, don't forget to google the term "sunk-cost fallacy", it will help ;)

Comment: Thanks. I read about it, It made me feel better

Answer (score 10):

As sad as it is, if the situation did not improve in six years, it will (most likely) not improve any time soon.

Here are some (the only?) alternatives you should have in mind.

1. Forget about remaining balance. You will never see it. IF you will get it, it will be a reason to be happier.
2. Decide if the money you actually get is worth your remaining at this job. Are they enough to cover your expenses with your family? Do you / they have a decent life thanks to this money?
3. Is the money enough to justify you working more than 11 hours a day?
4. If it is not worth it, find another job and never look back.

Comment: Have you taken into account that OP is working in a golf emirate (those are notorious for giving few rights to foreign workers) and is probably from a developing country? Finding another job, preferably a better job, might be extremely difficult for them.

Comment: @Roland: Yes, I have. That is why I left the option of "find another job" as a last resort.

Answer (score 6):

> He just pays me 30%

That is incorrect. He pays you 100% of your salary every month, and both you and him pretend that there's more money coming in the future.

> he doubts my work ethics and thinks that I purposely don’t work

That is also incorrect. He puts on pressure so he can exploit you for financial gain. If he ever thought you purposely don't work, he would have fired and replaced you immediately.

In summary, your problem is that your job makes you unhappy, exhausts you, you're paid below market rate, there's an expectation of severe (economic) punishment if you quit, and there's no expectation that any of that will ever improve. You are a wage slave.

---

How to get out?

You have to look for a better job now. Not a job that pays more; a job that is better for you. Even if you go back to India: you may be paid less, but your expenses will be lower as well, your happiness will increase, you no longer have the work visa holding you hostage, and you will have a much easier time finding yet another job (even a job abroad) once you're in India.

Comment: Dear Mr. Peter, Thanks for the comment. Please elaborate me, how am I pretending  that more money will come in future. I am having a hope that i will paid for the things i am promised. Please enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: @Abdemus He is saying you are being conned and I completely agree. Your salary consists of what you take home *not* of what is promised to you with no legal paperwork. If you are promised payment 2x your the average salary but you only ever see 30% of it, you are actually being under paid for your skills compared to the market.

Answer (score 1):

I just have 2 things to point out:

> half of my salary is 2 times more than the market value salary

That means your salary is 4X market value, and you are also saying you get paid 30% of that. Hence, you are being paid only 20% over market which is still pretty good. As others pointed out: forget about those 70%, it will never be paid off.

Second thing: as you are looking for another job or not, start accumulating paper trail. Try to interact more via email, rather than in-person, or follow-up every verbal communication with email saying something like:

> Hi boss, I wanted to confirm as we discussed yesterday that project is on time, and my plan is acceptable.

Just in case you decide to get a lawyer, paper trail will come in handy. Especially it might be useful to get written verification of that promised salary.

Comment: @Abdemus don't forget to upvote and accept most helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you're going to have to hear.  The first is the one that everyone is saying.  That money is gone.  It does not exist.  It will never exist.  He will never pay it to you no matter what happens.  He is simply using it as a way to staple you in place.

The second is harsher.  Your boss is abusing you psychologically.  He is questioning your loyalty and dedication as a way of beating you down, in spite of the fact tat your loyalty and dedication are obvious.  He is using psychological tools to keep you from fleeing, and then attacking you emotionally so that you won't have the willpower to oppose him.  He is treating you terribly, and it is almost certainly warping your ability to even think about behaving in ways that he doesn't want you to behave.  These are standard psychological techniques of abusive people.

You have no options for getting that money.  Your options are two - you can suck down the abuse and the 11-hour days, for the money that you're currently being paid, or you can walk, possibly after finding a new job.  Those are your options.  I would suggest that you find a new job and then walk.  Continuing to subject yourself to an abusive boss will not benefit you in the long run.  It will only break you further.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However in past I had tried to find the jobs, But being on job for 11 hours, it is very difficult to find a job, To find a job of my satisfaction , I have to search very aggressively, Which is only possible if I leave the job, as after working 11 hours i dont have the time, Please advise. Thanks

Comment: @Abdemus that does not change your options.  It just means that the "leave" option is "leave, then find job" rather than "find job, then leave".  Understand that the effects of the abuse are going to make it harder for you to want to leave.  You will constantly be thinking of reasons why you cannot or should not.  Still, if your actual money in hand literally is twice what you would get elsewhere (and it's not just your boss saying that) then maybe it is worth sticking around in this toxic work environment in order to get that money.

Comment: Dear Mr. Ben,  Thanks for the commen. At times I feel like dying rather than facing him again.